# How to query from a database in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm still somewhat new to ASP.NET and VB, and I found out that it's vastly different from the ASP I learned where I used `Recordset` to extract data from the database. Can someone give me some pointers on how to extract data from a database? Here is what I used to at least connect:

```
Dim conn As OdbcConnection
conn = New OdbcConnection("DSN=southwind")
Dim mystring as String = "SELECT GroupName FROM Group"
Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(mystring, conn)

conn.Open()
Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

The last line gives me an error saying:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'.
```

But since I don't quite understand ASP.NET completely, not too sure what it means even though the syntax looks fine. Removing that line runs the code just fine. How would I display all the contents from the `GroupName` column in table `Group`?

EDIT: Thanks everyone, I completely forgot that Group was reserved in SQL.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `GROUP` is a reserved word, part of the `GROUP BY` clause. That same query would not have worked with classic ASP either.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to connect to SQL Server. You might want to use the `System.Data.Sql` library instead of the ODBC stuff.

Comment: You really ought to change the name of the Group column if you can. You're colliding with a reserved word...

Comment: Is there an advantage to using `System.Data.Sql` over `ODBC`? And is there an example I can follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Group` is a keyword in SQL, you need to wrap it in square brackets like this,

```
SELECT GroupName FROM [Group]
```

This would assume the Group to be a name of the table, instead of a key word;  of `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Group is a keyword in SQL.  If your table name or column names referenced in your query are keywords, you can enclose them in brackets.

```
Dim mystring as String = "SELECT GroupName FROM [Group]"
```